# Apache unintentional redirect between named virtual hosts

Tags: apache, redirect, vhosts

I'm experiencing a problem with an unintentional redirect between two virtual hosts. I'm pretty sure it's a simple configuration error, but as often happens I'm having trouble seeing my own mistake.

Details: Running Apache2 on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

I have three named virtual hosts specified in sites-available.

Two of the hosts work as expected: entering the domain name (`hostname1.com` or `hostname2.com`) in the address bar of a browser opens the correct file from `/var/www/host_name1/public_html` or `/var/www/host_name2/public_html`.

However, entering the third domain name (`host_name3.com`) in the browser address bar opens `host_name2.com`, showing the index file in `/var/www/host_name2/public_html`. Oddly, entering `host_name3.com/index.html` in the browser results in the correct page from `/var/www/host_name3.com/public_html` being shown.

I have checked the virtual host files and they appear (to me) to be correct:

Host_name1.com.conf

```
    ServerAdmin admin@host_name1.com
    ServerName host_name1.com
    ServerAlias www.host_name1.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/host_name1.com/public_html
```

Host_name2.com.conf

```
    ServerAdmin admin@host_name2.com
    ServerName host_name2.com
    ServerAlias www.host_name2.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/host_name2.com/public_html
```

Host_name3.com.conf

```
    ServerAdmin admin@host_name3.com
    ServerName host_name3.com
    ServerAlias www.host_name3.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/host_name3.com/public_html
```

This all looks correct to me. DNS seems to be working as expected... DiG returns the correct domain/IP info for all three domain names. Apache logs don't see to show anything out of the ordinary.

Anyone willing to make a guess as to what I've incorrectly configured, point me to somewhere to look for a mistake that has this as its symptom, or otherwise help me figure this out?

Thanks,
Dan

Comment: Check for symlinks. Also try to create a file in /var/www/host_name3.com/public_html/test.html and access it from browser to verify if it works properly

Comment: A direct link to host_name3.com/index.html or host_name3.com/test.html works as expected. The only thing that seems to be a problem is opening host_name3.com--which results in the address redirecting to host_name2.com (and displaying its index.html page)--I don't see any symlinks in the /var/www/host_name directories, is there somewhere else I should check?

Comment: Additional info... I just added a fourth domain/DNS entry and it also is redirecting to host_name2.com

Comment: Do you have any redirect rule in place.

Comment: @KNOWARTH: I don't have any redirect rule in place... this is a fresh apache2 install that I've only modified by adding and enabling these four sites. My previous post about site #4 was in error: I had forgotten to enable the site--once corrected, browsers pointed at domain 4 do arrive at the correct domain and page

Comment: Here's the content of the .conf file
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin admin@domain1.com
        ServerName domain1.com
        ServerAlias www.domain1.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/domain1.com/public_html
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin admin@domain2.com
        ServerName domain2.com
        ServerAlias www.domain2.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/domain2.com/public_html
</VirtualHost>